# Crystal Report - How to sum by item number during a time period

Tags: date, crystal-reports, sum, range

I am wondering if we can sum by item number which looks like sum(quantity, item#) but I don't know if I want it to sum the quantity specific from date A to date B how can i do that. Please let me know if you figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a formula field:

```
//{@quantity}
If {view.date_field} In Date(2013,06,01) To Date(2013,06,30) Then
  {view.item_quantity}
```

Insert a group on the {view.item_number} field (Insert | Group...)

Insert a summarized field on the formula field (Insert | Summary...), specify the group that you just created.

Answer (score 0):

the answer lies within your question, the formula that you have written is called conditional sum.

```
sum(quantity, item#);
```

create a formula writing exactly the same thing, but replacing the arguments with the actual database fields which I assume would make the formula, somewhat like this.

```
sum({view.item_quantity}, {view.item_number});
```

hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I want to know how to conditionally summing the quantity within certain time period. That's why the formula itself is limited on this function.